# How to use remove() (Firebase SDK 9 web)

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database

How to use "remove()" in SDK v9 web?

(context: I'm learning React Native (using Expo) and there's this todo app).

There are no examples in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write). Here is what I have:

```
    // firebase
import app from "./firebaseConfig";
 
import {
  getDatabase,
  ref,
  set,
  push,
  onValue,
  remove,
  child,
} from "firebase/database";
 
// etc
 
const db = getDatabase(app);
const taskListRef = ref(db, "tarefas/" + user);
const newTaskRef = push(taskListRef);
 
// etc
 
const handleDelete = (key) => {
    remove(taskListRef).then(() => {
      const findTasks = tasks.filter((item) => item.key !== key);
      setTasks(findTasks);
    });
  };
```

So, this **remove(taskListRef)** is my problem. I don't know how to call it properly regarding the reference to the data location.

I've tried: remove(taskListRef.*child(user)*), remove(taskListRef.*child(key)*) etc... and a bunch of other similar things. The error always: wrong reference.

Here is the [repo](https://github.com/jcgsr/jan-RNTarefas/tree/main). Please, help. Thank you all in advance.

P.S.: hopefully I won't have to ask a similar question regarding **update()**.